# Reflecting primitive types such as "double" results in unexpected output

Tags: dart

The following example fails with:

```
FAIL: MyClass tests getClassReturnsConstructorForDouble
  Expected: ?:<double>
    Actual: ?:<double>
```

Example:

```dart
test("getClassReturnsConstructorForDouble", () {
    double object = 10.1;
    Type objectClass = reflect(object).type.reflectedType;      
    expect(objectClass, equals(object.runtimeType));
});
```

Is it not possible to accurately reflect int/double types?

Comment: This is either a bug - or an ugly wart due to dart2js compatibility. I've put a comment against this bug. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6433

Comment: More discussion about this here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/177awsJLvUE

Answer (score 6):

reflectedType gets you the true implementation type. The runtimeType can lie, and does, by design.

There can be varying implementations for numbers of various sorts of numbers, for strings and other built in types, but the they are exposed as the publicly known ones.

For example, we might have different implementation types for integers of varying size, but they will all say their runtimeType is int. If you reflect on them, you can see the difference.

Another example might be String. There may be specialized classes for strings that are pure ASCII for example, because they can be represented more compactly. This is not exposed at the base level: the runtimeType is String. You cannot detect this unless you dig for it via reflection.

Comment: Should there be a way to "loosely" compare Types returned by reflectedType and runtimeType other than using toString() as in the answer above? (By loosely I mean all different kinds of double are equal to other kinds of double, and for Strings etc)

Comment: It looks like the solution will be TypeMirror.isAssignableFrom(t) https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13856

Answer (score 0):

I think reflection is returning the correct types to you, but your test fails because objectClass and object.runtimeType are two seperate objects and therefore not equal to each other. If you convert them to string first they will equal each other:

```dart
expect(objectClass.toString(), equals(object.runtimeType.toString()));
```