# Under what circumstances does reflectClass(o.runtimeType) return a different result from reflect(o).type?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

from the [dartdocs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-mirrors.InstanceMirror@id_type) for `InstanceMirror.type`:

"Returns a mirror on the actual class of the reflectee. The class of the reflectee may differ from the object returned by invoking runtimeType on the reflectee."

so under what circumstances does `reflectClass(o.runtimeType)` return a different result from `reflect(o).type`?

I have tried with example code:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A{}

void main() {

  var string = "str";
  var boolean = true;
  var integer = 5;
  var map = {};
  var list = [];
  var custom = new A();

  var strRunT = string.runtimeType;
  var strRefT = reflect(string).type.reflectedType;
  var boolRunT = boolean.runtimeType;
  var boolRefT = reflect(boolean).type.reflectedType;
  var intRunT = integer.runtimeType;
  var intRefT = reflect(integer).type.reflectedType;
  var mapRunT = map.runtimeType;
  var mapRefT = reflect(map).type.reflectedType;
  var listRunT = list.runtimeType;
  var listRefT = reflect(list).type.reflectedType;
  var cusRunT = custom.runtimeType;
  var cusRefT = reflect(custom).type.reflectedType;

  print('string');
  print('runtimeType = $strRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $strRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${strRunT == strRefT}');
  print('runT == String = ${strRunT == String}');
  print('refT == String = ${strRefT == String}');
  print('');
  print('bool');
  print('runtimeType = $boolRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $boolRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${boolRunT == boolRefT}');
  print('runT == bool = ${boolRunT == bool}');
  print('refT == bool = ${boolRefT == bool}');
  print('');
  print('integer');
  print('runtimeType = $intRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $intRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${intRunT == intRefT}');
  print('runT == int = ${intRunT == int}');
  print('refT == int = ${intRefT == int}');
  print('');
  print('map');
  print('runtimeType = $mapRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $mapRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${mapRunT == mapRefT}');
  print('runT == Map = ${mapRunT == Map}');
  print('refT == Map = ${mapRefT == Map}');
  print('');
  print('list');
  print('runtimeType = $listRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $listRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${listRunT == listRefT}');
  print('runT == List = ${listRunT == List}');
  print('refT == List = ${listRefT == List}');
  print('');
  print('custom');
  print('runtimeType = $cusRunT');
  print('reflectedType = $cusRefT');
  print('runT == refT = ${cusRunT == cusRefT}');
  print('runT == A = ${cusRunT == A}');
  print('refT == A = ${cusRefT == A}');
  print('');
}


//OUTPUT
string
runtimeType = String
reflectedType = String
runT == refT = false
runT == String = true
refT == String = false

bool
runtimeType = bool
reflectedType = bool
runT == refT = true
runT == bool = true
refT == bool = true

integer
runtimeType = int
reflectedType = int
runT == refT = false
runT == int = true
refT == int = false

map
runtimeType = _LinkedHashMap
reflectedType = _LinkedHashMap
runT == refT = true
runT == Map = false
refT == Map = false

list
runtimeType = List
reflectedType = List
runT == refT = true
runT == List = false
refT == List = false

custom
runtimeType = A
reflectedType = A
runT == refT = true
runT == A = true
refT == A = true
```

additionally is there anyway of comparing 2 `Type`s and finding if they are equal? as the example above shows that the 2 seperate Types of `int` aren't equal using the regular `==` operator.

Answer (score 4):

You will get different results when a class *overrides* the `runtimeType` member. Basically an Object can *lie* on its type.

You can read more in the thread : [example of wanting to override runtimeType?](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/XZbhI1N9Ads).

Answer (score 4):

An example of what Alexandre said is the String type. In dart:core the String class overrides runtimeType to always return the base class type String. However in the VM there are a number of different runtime subtypes for String. i.e single character strings, ascii strings, utf8 strings. The mirror api returns the real underlying subtype.

See Gilad's (the API's designer) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245748/reflecting-primitive-types-such-as-double-results-in-unexpected-output/20253047#20253047) to this SO question.

> "is there anyway of comparing 2 Types and finding if they are equal?"

There are three new methods [coming soon](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=32577) that allow you to compare types when using mirrors: TypeMirror.isSubtypeOf, TypeMirror.isAssignableTo, ClassMirror.isSubclassOf.